# Method overload in c# returns wrong result with different return type

Tags: c#, oop, methods, type-conversion, overloading

I tried checking for method overloading in c# 
As Following code output is 21 instead of 22. Is it correct?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double d = AddTwoNumbers(10 , 10);
            Console.Write("Result : {0}", d);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static int AddTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b + 1;
        }

        static double AddTwoNumbers(double a, double b)
        {
            return a + b + 2;
        }
```

Comment: The best overload is chosen by the method parameters, not the return type. Try `AddTwoNumbers(10d , 10d)` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`10` is treated as `integer`, not `double` unless you specify it explicitly:

```
// using 'd' literal
double d = AddTwoNumbers(10d , 10d);

// Or via explicit cast
double d = AddTwoNumbers((double)10, (double)10);
```

Comment: But return type is double so compiler should treat the second method as compatible.

Comment: @Shri return type is not a part of overload resolution